# three.js MeshToonMaterial in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I import THREE.js:

`import * as THREE from 'three';`

But I don't have THREE.MeshToonMaterial
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshToonMaterial

`error TS2551: Property 'MeshToonMaterial' does not exist`

my dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
    "@types/three": "^0.84.22",
    "three": "^0.87.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.3.7"
  },`

Most of THREE materials are imported

[image: VS Code hints]

Comment: MeshToonMaterial definitely exists in three 0.87.1 (you're welcome to inspect the Node Module to confirm). Can you share your actual code? I'm guessing human error.

Comment: I found its JS version in node_modules [link](https://imgur.com/gallery/7AW7v), but I guess typescript needs some definitions

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe this will help:
[link](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/18481#pullrequestreview-53987617)

Comment: @Mikemike did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JamesThurley I use `declare class MeshToonMaterial extends MeshPhongMaterial{}` Based on [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshToonMaterial) it looks like the only changed/new properties are 'gradientMap', 'isMeshToonMaterial', 'defines'